# Parameters in mlemodel in statsmodel

Tags: python, statsmodels, state-space-models, linear-dynamical-system, nonlinear-dynamical-system

I am trying to run a TVP-VAR on statsmodel for a big data, but seems to run in a problem when I am trying to validate the vector matrix and the vector shape. Particularly, in the start and the update parameter definition mostly on the dimension and the structure of the update parameters

My model is a TVP-PVAR in a Normal Linear State- Space Model composed of the State Equation and the Measurement Equation. This is a big data, therefore I am using large number of varaibles in the model. My model equations are:

[image]

Where X ̃t=XtΞ and ut=Xt′+ut with Ut∼N(0,(I+σ2Xt′Xt))×Σ

The tracebak is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/user/Documents/PYTHON/Spider/tvp/tvpstandard5.py", line 246, in <module>
    preliminary = mod.fit(maxiter=1000)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 704, in fit
    mlefit = super(MLEModel, self).fit(start_params, method=method,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 563, in fit
    xopt, retvals, optim_settings = optimizer._fit(f, score, start_params,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py", line 241, in _fit
    xopt, retvals = func(objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py", line 651, in _fit_lbfgs
    retvals = optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, start_params, maxiter=maxiter,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 197, in fmin_l_bfgs_b
    res = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, bounds=bounds,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 306, in _minimize_lbfgsb
    sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 261, in _prepare_scalar_function
    sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._update_fun()

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 233, in _update_fun
    self._update_fun_impl()

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 137, in update_fun
    self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 134, in fun_wrapped
    return fun(np.copy(x), *args)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 531, in f
    return -self.loglike(params, *args) / nobs

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 933, in loglike
    self.update(params, transformed=True, includes_fixed=True,

  File "/Users/user/Documents/PYTHON/Spider/tvp/tvpstandard5.py", line 218, in update
    self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])  # W

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 239, in __setitem__
    return self.ssm.__setitem__(key, value)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/representation.py", line 420, in __setitem__
    setattr(self, key, value)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/representation.py", line 54, in __set__
    value = self._set_matrix(obj, value, shape)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/representation.py", line 68, in _set_matrix
    validate_matrix_shape(

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/tools.py", line 1474, in validate_matrix_shape
    raise ValueError('Invalid dimensions for %s matrix: requires %d'

ValueError: Invalid dimensions for state covariance matrix matrix: requires 702 rows, got 3
```

I am providing code to check with you, what have I done wrong :

```
class TVPVAR(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    

                        
        
    def __init__(self, y):
        # Create a matrix with [y_t' : y_{t-1}'] for t = 2, ..., T
        augmented = sm.tsa.lagmat(y, 1, trim='both', original='in', use_pandas=True)
        # Separate into y_t and z_t = [1 : y_{t-1}']
      
        p = y.shape[1]
        y_t = augmented.iloc[:, :p]
        z_t = sm.add_constant(augmented.iloc[:, p:])
        nobs = y.shape[0]
        T=y.shape[0]
         
        # Recall that the length of the state vector is p * (p + 1)
        k_states = p * (p + 1)
        super(TVPVAR,self).__init__(y_t, exog=None, k_states=k_states,k_posdef=k_states)
    
        
        self.k_y = p
        self.k_states = p * (p + 1)  
        self.nobs = T  
        self['design'] = np.zeros((self.k_y, self.k_states, 1))  
        
        self['transition'] = np.eye(k_states) # G
        self['selection'] = np.eye(k_states) # R=1
        
     
        
    def update_variances(self, obs_cov, state_cov_diag):
        self['obs_cov'] = obs_cov
        self['state_cov'] = np.diag(state_cov_diag)    # W
        init = initialization.Initialization(self.k_states)
        init.set((0, 2), 'diffuse')
        init.set((2, 4), 'stationary')
        self.ssm.initialize(init)
         

         
    
    def constrain_stationary_multivariate(unconstrained, variance,
                                      transform_variance=False,
                                      prefix=None):
      
        
      unconstrained =np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y * order)
      variance=np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y)
       
      order  = k_y
      
      prefix = find_best_blas_type(
            [unconstrained, variance])
      dtype = prefix_dtype_map[prefix]

      unconstrained = np.asfortranarray(unconstrained, dtype=dtype)
      variance = np.asfortranarray(variance, dtype=dtype)
      # Step 1: convert from arbitrary matrices to those with singular values
      # less than one.
      # sv_constrained = _constrain_sv_less_than_one(unconstrained, order,
      #                                              k_y, prefix)

      sv_constrained = prefix_sv_map[prefix](unconstrained, order, k_y)
      # Step 2: convert matrices from our "partial autocorrelation matrix"
      # space (matrices with singular values less than one) to the space of
      # stationary coefficient matrices
      constrained, variance = prefix_pacf_map[prefix](
        sv_constrained, variance, transform_variance, order, k_y)

      constrained = np.zeros_like(constrained, dtype=dtype)
      variance = np.zeros_like(variance, dtype=dtype)

      return constrained, variance
      
   
    def unconstrain_stationary_multivariate(constrained, error_variance):
       
       constrained= np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y * order)
       error_variance=np.zeros_like(k_y * k_y)
       # Step 1: convert matrices from the space of stationary
    # coefficient matrices to our "partial autocorrelation matrix" space
    # (matrices with singular values less than one)
       partial_autocorrelations = _compute_multivariate_pacf_from_coefficients(
        constrained, error_variance, order, k_y)
       unconstrained = _unconstrain_sv_less_than_one(
        partial_autocorrelations, order, k_y)
       return unconstrained, error_variance
      
        
      
    def update(self, params, **kwargs):
        params = super().update(params, **kwargs)
        self['transition', 2,2] = params[0]
        self['transition', 3,2] = params[1]
        self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])  # W
    
    
   
    @property
    def state_names(self):
        state_names = np.empty((self.k_y, self.k_y + 1), dtype=object)
        for i in range(self.k_y):
            endog_name = self.y__names[i]
            state_names[i] = (
                ['intercept.%s' % y_name] +
                ['L1.%s->%s' % (other_name, y_name) for other_name in self.y_names])
        return state_names.ravel().tolist()
    
    
    @property
    def start_params(self):
       return np.r_[0, 0, 1e-5, 1e-5, 1e-5]
   
    
    @property
    def param_names(self):
        return ['level0', 'phi', 'sigma2.ar1', 'sigma2.level', 'sigma2.slope']
    
    
mod = TVPVAR(y)
index=year

preliminary = mod.fit(maxiter=1000)



res = mod.fit(preliminary.params, method='nm', disp=0, maxiter=1000) 
print(res.summary())
```

Thanks to everyone for their time in helping me with this.

Comment: You have specified k_states=702, which means the state_cov matrix must be 702 x 702. In the update method, you’re trying to set the state_cov to be a 3x3 matrix. The error is telling you that the state_cov cannot be a 3x3 matrix

Comment: @cfulton
 Thank you for stopping by and commenting.  Two questions: 
1. How could I modify properly my code in order to get the right results? 
2) Since this is a TVP-VAR, and unit root is assumed, my understanding is that I have to keep only the " diffuse''and   remove the "stationarity " . Same goes for "constrain_stationary_multivariate" and "unconstrain_stationary_multivariate". 
Am I getting this right? 
Much appreciate a full version of the code!